# Split HTML table across multiple layout columns (in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, multiple-columns

This is a problem that mostly seems to apply to Firefox. I have a two column layout in HTML using the following CSS Styles:

```
div.column-container {
   -webkit-column-count: 2;
   -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
   -moz-column-count: 2;
   -moz-column-gap: 10px;
   column-count: 2;
   column-gap: 10px;
}
```

This works great for text and general content, but I have a large table that I would like to have split across both columns and as it seems right now, the table just goes into one or the other column.

I tried various approaches such as

```
div.column-container tr {
   page-break-after: auto;
   page-break-before: auto;
}
```

but this did not seem to help.

Here is a fiddle illustrating the situation: http://jsfiddle.net/hq2uukm5/1/

Does anyone have any idea how a table can be broken across multiple columns?

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few random ideas but couldn't get anything to work in Firefox.

The only things I did come up with were to fix the top border being hidden on the second column and fixing the big gap between the columns in chrome..

```
div.column-container { display: inline-block; }

tr:nth-child(33) td {
border-width: 2px 1px 1px 1px;
}
```

So, this is not a direct answer to the question but an alternative method for those not requiring an actual table but wanting a table-style layout.

html

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="table">
    <div class="tr"><div class="td">Test</div><div class="td">Test</div><div class="td">Test</div></div>
    <div class="tr"><div class="td">Test</div><div class="td">Test</div><div class="td">Test</div></div>
    <div class="tr"><div class="td">Test</div><div class="td">Test</div><div class="td">Test</div></div>
    <div class="tr"><div class="td">Test</div><div class="td">Test</div><div class="td">Test</div></div>
</div><!-- end table -->

</div><!-- end wrapper -->
```

css

```
.wrapper {
    text-align: center; /* table needs a wrapper to center it */
}

.table {
    display: inline-block; /* required to keep a nice spacing between columns */
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-gap: 10px;
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 10px;
}

.tr {
    display: block;
}

.td {
    display: inline-block;
    border-width: 1px 0px 0px 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* the following is to make borders even on all cells, something that tables do better than divs */

.td:last-child {
    border-width: 1px 1px 0px 1px;
}

.tr:last-child {
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
}

.tr:nth-child(6) {
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #000000;
}
```

fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/mmoh8kkd/

and if your row count constantly changes, a fiddle for that (borders not even)

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/jru2a5ta/

Comment: Little change https://jsfiddle.net/7y5sun0c/ , `display: table-row` for `.tr`, `display: table-cell` for `.td`